# Finding area between two curves(each consists of an array of points)

Tags: java, android, math, calculus

I'm writing an android application that scans an image and creates a sort of histogram from said image, then allows the user to drag a baseline of a predefined number of points. I have these parts completed, but now I need to be able to estimate the integral between the 1000 or so points from the scanned image and the user defined baseline consisting of any number of points, over a set interval(will probably be decided by an algorithm that decides where the max/mins are and inflection points). Each array of points define a single line.

Is there any existing library that will take Point[] arrays and find the estimated area between two lines? Or do I need to write a custom algorithm myself to handle this? I looked at apache common math, but it seemed to need a math function to be passed in to be able to find an integral.

edit:
line 1 is an array of about 1000 points(depends on image resolution) 
{(0,5),(1,10), (2,11), (3,9), ....(1000,12)}

line 2 might be 5 points(user decides):
{(0,5), (250,9), (500,7), (750,8), (1000,5)}

Real y-values will be much larger, but this is the general idea.

Comment: You need to integrate that area. It depends what function represent these two curves http://www.ee.ucl.ac.uk/~mflanaga/java/Integration.html
See the lib here

Comment: There is no function representing the curves, they are real data points. The only "function" I can extract is the function that exists between every 2 points, which would mean finding a function for some 1000 lines and integrating them to arrive at a result.

Comment: create a new line f(x) = y0, which is below both lines, and devide the line (original Point[]) into trapezoids (using the points you have), you will reach the new shape's area by doing so and summing the trapezoids. do it for both lines, and subtract one from the other, and you got your area. shouldn't be more then 20 lines of code

Comment: @John well, there is a function, it's just you don't have a *symbolic* representation of it. So you need to do **numerical integration**, for which I'm sure you'll be able to find a library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I completely understand what you want, but if you'd like to find the area of a polygon defined by points resulting from your image and those from the user drawing a baseline you could use [this very simple equation for the area of a non-intersecting polygon](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygonArea.html)

Comment: This looks like an interesting way to tackle this problem, so I would just then reverse the order of my baseline, and add it to the end of my histogram lines, making a point array of a clockwise polygon, then use that second formula to arrive at the area?

Comment: @John correct. You should dispose of the sign if you have CW ordering of points.

Comment: So this gives me the benefit of finding the exact area with a relatively low complexity algorithm? Compared to doing traditional integral estimation with Riemann sums.

Comment: @John yeah, it works great. I've used it before. Two lines of code in Mathematica. Very fast.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand what you want.

**but I thought of 2 things:**

If you want to calculate the integral of an histogram, from n points (xi,yi=f(xi)) you can use [Rieman integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral) to get the value.

with the followin formula: 
[image]

They are other representation of Rienmann integrals like trapezoids instead of histogram ,etc...

for example if `ti=(xi+xi+1)/2` you would get trapezoids

**Other possibility:**

You can use a [polynome to interpolate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation) the 1000 values.

You will get a function f such that, f(xi)=yi for your all your (xi,yi) points.

Then calculate the integral of the polynomial function (easy since you can find an explicit primitiv)

**example**:

if P is the polynom

I the integral

p the primitive of P

I=p(xmax)-p(xmin)

**Note:**

If you have 2 lines, just substract one integral by the other.

Hope I understood the question and it helps

Comment: line 1 is an array of about 1000 points {(0,5),(1,10), (2,11), (3,9), ....(1000, 12)}

line 2 might be 5 points(user decides):{(0,5), (250,9), (500,7), (750,8), (1000,5)}

Comment: @john For this kind of situation I would advise the interpolation polynome since the Rieman will just represent your points as a histogram or a trapezoid depending on the Riemann integral you chose.

Comment: @John Sjoerd algorithm might be a best fit for what you're looking for.